# Excel Nesting IF in SumIfs

Tags: excel, nested

Ok. So i'm looking to nest `IF` in my `SUMIFS` formulas. The only problem i'm having is when one of my referenced cells show `FALSE`, the formula no longer works. How do i get the formula to completely remove that Criteria from the `SUMIFS` formula and still work?

Codes i've used.

```
=SUMIFS(R:R,IF(BE4=TRUE,I:I),IF(BE4=TRUE,BD4),J:J,BD5)

=IF(BE4=TRUE,SUMIFS(R:R,I:I,BD4),0)+IF(BE5=TRUE,SUMIFS(R:R,J:J,BD5),0)
```

I've even tried breaking the `SUMIFS` formula into multiple cells, and using `IF` and `INDIRECT` to create a working code. Just keeps popping up with `#REF` error.

Here's that code

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(BK1,IF(BE2=TRUE,BK2,""),IF(BE3=TRUE,BK3,""),IF(BE4=TRUE,BK4,""),IF(BE5=TRUE,BK5,""),BK6))
```

Here's the code that didn't work before the IF.

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(BK1,BK2,BK3,BK4,BK5,BK6))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Mock Sheet
https://www.dropbox.com/s/tl64vbsalcqxqdm/CriteriaIFS.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: TY, was in the process of fixing that.

Comment: Could you provide an screenshot of the data... or may be the data (in a text table format)?

Comment: Check this link [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) Because the way you are using the formula is not right... see: **Syntax: SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)** You are sending an single cell where you need to send a range (as you are using R:R to perfom the sum, you need to put the whole column in the other `criteria_range`

Comment: Ok, i can't upload the actual spread sheet since it holds a lot of private information. But i can do screen shots.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZxS0.png Main Sheet

http://i.stack.imgur.com/XC9Ln.png Inventory

http://i.stack.imgur.com/VmuFV.png Markup area on inventory sheet

Comment: Lastly. If you look at the main sheet. It shows the current quantities of the drive i have selected on the inventory sheet (Uses VBA to put the info up top) On the main sheet, i use check boxes to add which drive info to the listing i would like. Now, i would also like the quantities to update according to the information i've selected to use. (which is the current issue for this whole question/post)

Comment: I do not think this is possible with formulas.  you are basically asking for 16 different formulas nested inside of 15 if statements.  The best way would be to the best would be to use vba to build the formula based on the 4 True/False categories.

Comment: Never mind my last comment.  See my most recent edit.  It should do what you want.

Comment: @Scott I'm trying this, and it keeps showing a 0 for the value on the mock sheet

Comment: Did you hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter to exit edit mode?

Comment: Yeah, I am back to vba being the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(BK1:BK6,BK1:BK6,">=0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula,

```
=IF(BE4=TRUE,SUMIFS(R:R,I:I,BD4,J:J,BD5),SUMIFS(R:R,J:J,BD5))
```

Your formula

```
=SUMIFS(R:R,IF(BE4=TRUE,I:I),IF(BE4=TRUE,BD4),J:J,BD5)
```

You are saying: 
Sum from `column R` everything if match in `J` with `BD5` and `IF BE4 is TRUE` `THEN` in `I` `IF` match with `BD5`. Well, the error is because, if `BE4` is true is returning a string not a range. Instead you could use this:

```
=SUMIFS(R:R,INDIRECT(IF(BE4=TRUE,I:I)),INDIRECT(IF(BE4=TRUE,BD4)),J:J,BD5)
```

And it will be ok, until `BE4` is `FALSE`. because the `INDIRECT` function return an `#REF!`... and will be a mess.

I'm not sure if I get the whole idea, but please tell me if you need an emprovement.

**Edit #1**

Reading your comments I think this could help:

```
=IF(BE4=TRUE,SUMIFS(R:R,I:I,BD4),0)+IF(BE4=TRUE,SUMIFS(R:R,J:J,BD5))
```

Try to post some dummie database  [(using text table format)](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) to give you a better help... and remember to read this: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) because your question is to vague, and it was necesary to many comments and answers to "guess" what you really want.

Comment: BE2 = Criteria 1
BE3 = Criteria 2
BE4 = Criteria 3
BE5 = Criteria 4. If BE3 shows false while the other show true, i just want to do sumifs(criteria1,criteria3,critera4)

This will show me how many relative drives i have in my inventory according to how Specific i am creating my listing. So, if i remove any amount of the criterias, my count should go up. And same with adding more, specifics to my listing will bring the quantity of relative drives down.

Comment: You want a Checking/Selecting SUMIFS... If any of the criteria is true, then, use it, if not, don't use it??? That is?? Add and remove parts of the formula, by checking if in BE is or not true???

Comment: It was hard to understand until now... and without the data is harder... But did you try VBA??? And why not try to split every criteria into a IF + IF this way: `IF(BE1=TRUE,SUMIFS(R,CRITERIA_RANGE1,CRITERIA1)) +  IF(BE2=TRUE,SUMIF()) + IF(BE3=TRUE,SUMIFS())`

Comment: If i did IF+IF it would add the two quantities together, i dont want that

Comment: @RyanHubbard but if one is false then it would return 0 for that part and adding anything to zero is the first.

Comment: @Elbert. The problem with that is it adds the two quantities together and gives a value of 142. It found 48 of the first value and 94 of the 2nd. I need it to find how many of those two match on the same line out of those 142, which would be 24.

Comment: @Scott Craner That's the issue. I need it to Void out that Criteria from the SUMIFS if BE2-BE5 shows false, rather then adding a 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula:

```
 =SUMIFS(N:N,IF($A$2,E:E,T:T),IF($A$2,$C$2,""),IF($A$3,F:F,T:T),IF($A$3,$C$3,""),IF($A$4,H:H,T:T),IF($A$4,$C$4,""),IF($A$5,I:I,T:T),IF($A$5,$C$5,""))
```

It is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

This is based on your data sheet provided.  You will need to change the references to your sheet.  The column T reference should be a column that is empty.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Almost. The problem with that is it adds the two quantities together and gives a value of 142. It found 48 of the first value and 94 of the 2nd. I need it to find how many of those two match on the same line out of those 142, which would be 24.

Comment: @RyanHubbard may be time to mock up some data and post it in your OP that shows the data and what you expect as a result.

Comment: i made a sheet to upload, how do i do that?

Comment: @RyanHubbard The best would be to link to a picture loaded to imugr.  Or you could paste it to an open google sheet.

Comment: @RyanHubbard You will know if you confirmed it correctly as an Array formula if there are `{}` surrounding the formula.

Comment: @RyanHubbard I fixed it.  It had better work now or I am going to tear my hair out.

Comment: Are you getting it to work on the mock sheet? It's still coming up as 0 when i paste it in any cell as an array.

Comment: @RyanHubbard yes it is returning exactly what is expected depending on the TRUE/FALSE.  As these change so is the value.  See the picture.

Comment: @RyanHubbard maybe if you mock up the values in the actual columns and hide the rest I could help figure out where it is going wrong.

Comment: Well, the values at the top in column I with how those values should come about in column J. If you're getting the formula to work, could you somehow save it, and reupload it? No matter how i try your formula, it wont work.

Comment: Yes, i did. I've actually gotten much better at Excel and VBA since then by trial and error.. Thank you for asking.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the same thing. The formula needed to look at a different column as Criteria_Range2 depending on product.  I put an IF statement for both the Criteria_Range2, and for the Criteria2 because each column had slightly different information. Basically, it tells the formula use column C (in another worksheet) as the Criteria_Range2 if the product category is anything other than Ceilings.  If it is Ceilings, it uses column A as Criteria_Range2. On my worksheet, Column A is a "helper column" that groups our Ceilings sub-products into Tile and Grid.

Hopefully this isn't too confusing, but it works for me and I didn't easily find anything else out there showing how to use IF statements in the Criteria Ranges in the SUMIFS.  (I suggest ignoring the very ugly xlookup defining the sum_range.)

SUMIFS(XLOOKUP($AF$20&"COGS CM MTD",Fact_Sales!$E$6:$CS$6&Fact_Sales!$E$7:$CS$7,Fact_Sales!$E$8:$CS$928),Fact_Sales!$B$8:$B$928,'Report Draft'!$AE27,**IF(*'Report Draft'!$AD27<>"CEILINGS",Fact_Sales!$C$8:$C$928*,Fact_Sales!$A$8:$A$928)**,**IF(*'Report Draft'!$AD27<>"CEILINGS",'Report Draft'!$AD27*,'Report Draft'!$AF27)**)